# Универсальная ячейка с автозаполнением

Tags: swift, коллекции, tableview

Столкнулся с весьма сложной задачей (от того что не понимаю возможна ли реализация в swift)

Суть задачи:

Нужно создать "универсальную ячейку в tableView" или CollectionView
которая заполняется автоматически при ответе с сервера

Как она должна работать:

1. сервер присылает ответ с картинками, значением заголовка и значением подзаголовка.
2. строка может быть как на пол ячейки в ширину так и на всю.
3. Ячейка должна иметь автоматически генерирующую высоту

как это должно выглядеть я покажу на скриншоте ниже

http://joxi.ru/vAWLGjKHgLqXBr

Сервер может отдать что поле должно быть на половину ширины ячейки
Сервер может отдать что боле должно быть на ширину все ячейки 
Сервер может отдать высоту ячейки

сервер может вообще не отдать полей - тогда ячейки должно не быть

Подскажите, пожалуйста, тип реализации такой ячейки, с какими сложностями я могу столкнуться

Сейчас я вобще понятия не имею возможно ли это в свифте... так как именно в андроид решение было найдено

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно будет использовать `Stack View` и `Constraints` для такой реализации.

> сервер может вообще не отдать полей - тогда ячейки должно не быть

[UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview)

[Understanding Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/)

[Programmatically Creating Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html)

Comment: Спасибо, у меня начинает складываться понимание как это реализовать. 
Есть какой-то простой и действенный способ как преобразовать массивы в stackview? Сервер мне отдаёт набор массивов, у каждого одинаковые параметры и строки. В данный момент он может отдать от 1го до 20 массивов.

Comment: на самом деле у меня были ранее идеи как это сделать 

сделать стэки с таблиц, ячейки в стэках идут вплотную друг к другу
и каждый массив парсится и динамически создает нужное колличество элементов,
потом мне показалось это сложным в реализации и "игра не стоит свеч"

У меня и так внутри двух ячеек таблицы лежат еще одни коллекции с горизонтальной прокруткой